# Laravel Blade isset triggering error

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel Blade on my page and for some reason, the isset function isnt working properly. If the variable is not set, it triggers an error. Here is my code so far:

```
@if (isset($returns['Passive']))  //This is where the error is occuring
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><span>Passive Income</span>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><span>Passive: {{ $returns['Passive'] }}</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
@endif
```

I have no idea why it would cause an error, I have used isset on multiple pages before and it has never been an issue. Here is the error I am getting:

```
ErrorException: Undefined index: Passive (View: /home/unlikem5/public_html/myuladmin/resources/views/misc/paidPositions.blade.php) in /home/unlikem5/public_html/myuladmin/storage/framework/views/fc6ec53af49c1252e1698dacf9ac958b628485d5.php:16
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine. Any chance you may have cached a previous version of the view by mistake?

Comment: Tried clearing cache, still causing the same error

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the code of controller passing the returns variable to the view

Comment: to clear cache, you could use `php artisan view:clear` and yes, the `$returns` variable dump will be helpful, you could use `dd($returns)`.

Comment: try using `empty`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command and run again this will defenately solved your issue.

Clear all compiled view files:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score -2):

Laravel provides blade directives for `isset` and `empty` functions. Try this out -

> Laravel 5.6 Docs

```
@isset($records)
 // $records is defined and is not null...
@endisset

@empty($records)
 // $records is "empty"...
@endempty
```

Comment: That's why he's using `isset` function.`isset` check whether a key available or not

Comment: How naive of me, I have updated the answer @SupunPraneeth